# Create an Array of Unique Values from Similar Objects

Tags: java

I am trying to create an array of unique values based on the properties of a number of identical Objects. These properties will have identical values, but some of them will be `null`, like so:

```
Object obj1 = new Object("Value 1", "Value 2", null);
Object obj2 = new Object("Value 1", null, "Value 3");
Object obj3 = new Object(null, "Value2", "Value3")
```

Object Class

```
public class Object {
   private String value1;
   private String value2;
   private String value3;

   // Constructor
   public Object(String value1, String value2, String value3){ // this.value1... }

   // Getters & Setters
}
```

(These Objects can have `n` number of properties, but assume just 3 for this question)

How can I take the above 3 objects (or any number objects) and quickly combine (or sample) each of their properties to create the below array?

```
["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"]
```

I'm thinking a `Set` could be useful here, but I'm not quite sure how to approach it

Comment: How does your object class look like?

Comment: You need logic to determine uniqueness and/or equality.

Comment: @AmitBera assume it has just 3 String properties

Comment: I need to know how you have stored those values in your object class. Is your object class constructor is a varargs constructor and you are assigning all the passed values to any array? How can get the passed values from your object?

Comment: @KuraiBankusu He said it could be n number of properties

Comment: @AmitBera included the class definition, does that help?

Comment: Yes!! More clear now.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your Object look like this :

```
class MyObject {

    private String[] inputs;

    public MyObject(String... inputs) {
        this.inputs = inputs;
    }
    //Getters Setter

}
```

If you are using Java 8 you can use :

```
MyObject obj1 = new MyObject("Value 1", "Value 2", null);
MyObject obj2 = new MyObject("Value 1", null, "Value 3");
MyObject obj3 = new MyObject(null, "Value 2", "Value 3");

Set<String> result = Arrays.asList(obj1, obj2, obj3)
        .stream()
        .flatMap(item -> Stream.of(item.getInputs()))
        .filter(item -> item != null)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

System.out.println(result);
```

Outputs

```
[Value 3, Value 1, Value 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below solution :

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        MyObject obj1 = new MyObject("Value 1", "Value 2", null);
        MyObject obj2 = new MyObject("Value 1", null, "Value 3");
        MyObject obj3 = new MyObject(null, "Value 2", "Value 3");

        System.out.println(myObjectPropToStringArray(obj1,obj2,obj3));


    }

    public static Set<String> myObjectPropToStringArray(MyObject... myObject) {
        Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
        Arrays.stream(myObject).forEach(e ->{

            result.add(e.getValue1());
            result.add(e.getValue2());
            result.add(e.getValue3());
        });
        return result;
    }
}

 class MyObject {
       private String value1;
       private String value2;
       private String value3;



    public MyObject(String value1, String value2, String value3) {
        super();
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;
        this.value3 = value3;
    }

    public String getValue1() {
        return value1;
    }

    public void setValue1(String value1) {
        this.value1 = value1;
    }

    public String getValue2() {
        return value2;
    }

    public void setValue2(String value2) {
        this.value2 = value2;
    }

    public String getValue3() {
        return value3;
    }

    public void setValue3(String value3) {
        this.value3 = value3;
    }
 }
```

Comment: I would advise against using side effects to add to the `result` set and instead use `flatMap` with `Streams.of(e.getValue1(), e.getValue2(), e.getValue3())` followed by `collect(Collectors.toSet())`

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is just to pick all distinct values in each field of those objects, then you can work with lists of each field's values:

```
List<Object> objects = Arrays.asList(new Object("Value 1", "Value 2", null), 
          new Object("Value 1", null, "Value 3"), 
          new Object(null, "Value2", "Value3");

//This should give you the first list...
List<String> values = objects.stream().map(o ->
             Arrays.asList(o.getVal1(), o.getVal2(), o.getVal3()))
             .distinct()
             .findFirst().get();

//If you need to prefer non-null values, then you can use
//an ordered stream:
List<String> values = objects.stream()
            .map(o ->
                 Arrays.asList(o.getVal1(), o.getVal2(), o.getVal3()))
            .distinct().ordered(list -> 
                (list.get(0) != null ? -1 : 1)
              + (list.get(1) != null ? -1 : 1)
              + (list.get(2) != null ? -1 : 1))
            .findFirst()
            .get();
```

The comparator implementation is just to make non-null values come at the beginning of the stream so that `findFirst` can hit them first.
Of course you will need to check if the optional has a value.